# Does c# executable contain any informations about the compiler?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, security

I would like to know if its possible to extract informations about the computer on which c# application was compiled.

Lets take for example an app that was compiled on a computer with Visual Studio Community 2015.

Is it possible to extract user name of a creator, visual studio licence or any personal info from that executable?

Comment: You can probably extract the version of the compiler, and if there's a path to a PDB file embedded (and depending on what that path is), possibly the user name of the person who ran the build. But that's about it. Obviously the license and personal information is not going to be embedded. What made you think it is? What problem are you trying to solve here?

Comment: Everybody loves a Microsoft-is-evil story I guess.  But no, they do not disclose private details of their customers in such an obvious place.